# Problems with POSIX. Threads doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, unix, posix

I need to make for every column new thread and this tread need to sum up this column and show result. Main function must make mean of this sums.

Problem is in threads they don't sum kolumns or anything. Can you tell me why it does't work?

Here is code:

```
    #include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
struct argument
{
    int iteracja;
    double line;
    double kolumn;
    double **tablica;
    double suma_el;

};
void *suma(void *par);

int main()
{
    argument a1;                                        //element globalny żeby był też do wątków
    argument *p_a1=&a1; 
    a1.suma_el = 0;
    int line, kolumn;                           //ilosc lini i kolumn
    cout << "Podaj liczbe kolumn:" << endl;
    cin >> kolumn;                              //podajemy liczbe kolumn tym samym liczbe watkow
    p_a1->kolumn = kolumn;                      //liczbe kolumn wpisujemy do struktury przekazywanej do watku
    cout << "Podaj liczbę wierszy" << endl;
    cin >> line;                                //podajemy liczbe wierszy
    p_a1->line = line;                          //liczbe wierszy wpisujemy do struktury przekazywanej do watku
    double **tab = new double*[line];           //tworzymy tablice 2D 
    for (int i = 0; i < kolumn; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = new double[kolumn];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < kolumn; j++)
        {
            cout << "Podaj element [" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "] tablicy:" << endl;
            cin >> tab[i][j];
        }
    }
    p_a1->tablica= tab;
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)                          //wypelniona tablice 2D wypisujemy i przekazujemy do 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < kolumn; j++)
        {
            cout << tab[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < kolumn; i++)                                    //tworzymy watki a kazdy watek liczy nam sume 
    {
        (p_a1->iteracja) = i;
        pthread_t watek;
        pthread_create(&watek, NULL, suma, (void*)p_a1);
    }
    double srednia = 0;
    srednia = (p_a1->suma_el) / kolumn;
    cout << "Srednia suma kazdej kolumny wynosi:" << srednia << endl;
    return 0;
}

void *suma(void *par)
{
    argument struktura=*((argument*)par);
    argument *a = &struktura;
    double s = 0;
    int j = (a->iteracja);
    for (int k = 0; k < a->line; k++)
    {
        s = s + a->tablica[k][j];
    }
    cout << "Suma kolumny " << j << ":\t" << s << endl;
    (a->suma_el) = (a->suma_el) + s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a FYI; C++11 and above has built in support for threads which takes advantage of the type system.  IMHO that makes them a lot easier to use.

Comment: After you create a thread using `pthread_create` you never wait for it to finish it's job using `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems:

1. You are creating a bunch of threads in the loop near the end of `main()`, but you are not waiting for those threads to finish by using `pthread_join()`. As a result, you will often end up printing a result before all threads have finished their work.
2. In the function `suma`, you create a copy of the `struct argument *` structure in the local variable `struktura`, and only update the field `suma_el` in that local copy. When this function exits, the results of its work are not saved anywhere!
3. If the second issue were fixed, the final operation `(a->suma_el) = (a->suma_el) + s` does not use any form of synchronization, so multiple threads executing that operation simultaneously may overwrite each other's results.

Comment: i added `pthread_join(watek, NULL);` and i change in function: `argument *a; a=( argument * )par;` it still doesnt work. And any of these threads don't show sum for every's kolumn